# Acess components of included layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have an `activity`, in this `acitivity` `layout` file I have included another layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/activity_rating_header_layout"
        layout="@layout/activity_ratings_header" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My question is how do I access components of that included `layout` ? The included layout consists of some `textviews` for example, which are in **linear layout**. 
I have been trying to access them in this way :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();
    getEventID();

    View header = findViewById(R.id.activity_rating_header_linear_layout);

    mAverageView = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.activity_rating_header_average_number);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ratings);
    mAverageView.setText("Neviem");
}
```

but at the `onCreate` I am still getting null pointer in the `setText()` method. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `setContentView()` before you are trying to get the views. Put `setContentView` right on top, below the super call.